# Searching for a Fast Lossless Compression Technique

Tags: compression

I want to compress a string of bits and after that I want to decompress it. Can any body help me by mentioning a Fast Lossless Compression and Decompression Technique and if possible than it's programming implementation.

Comment: Also, what are you compressing? Is it for a specific purpose, or are you asking what is the best algorithm for unknown data?

Comment: You mention fast - is speed more important than compression ratio? Are you looking for an algorithm that is tuned for compression/decompression/both?

Comment: I am asking for known data i.e. a bit string. I am looking for an algorithm that is tuned for both compression & decompression.

Comment: *Bit string* is not "known data". Known data would be something like "text", "photographic image in format X", "sound in format Y", or such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for speed, then considering a fast compression algorithm like LZ4 makes sense.
Such algorithm is an order of magnitude faster than zlib/gzip (like 10x faster).
http://code.google.com/p/lz4/

Comment: Or LZO, which format is widely supported, and according to LZ4's website is only slightly inferior.

Comment: Well, the pb with LZO is that it is GPL.
LZ4 by contrast is BSD, so this is a no brainer from a license perspective.

Comment: Do you know how fast the lz4 is?
I tried to do lz4 with-1 option (to be the fastest) but I couldn't get a higher speed than 121MB / s, but as you may know, some people get higher speed! around 550MB/s for single core
I was wondering why that's happening?

Answer (score 2):

What about the ever-green called [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/) or [bzip2](http://bzip.org/)? They come already as library, ready to use.

Comment: Those aren't very fast though.

Answer (score 1):

gzip?

Algorithm can be found here:

http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt

Bonus: compatibility with pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

According to Matt Mahoney's Large Text Compression Benchmark (http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html) there are several very fast decompressors with good compression ratio:

- lzturbo 1.1       (-49 -b1000 -p0)  9 ns/byte decompression
- lzham alpha 3 x64 (-m4 -d29) 9 ns/byte decompression
- 4x4 / tornado - 9-13 ns/byte decompression
- libzling 20140430-bugfix (e4) 40 ns/byte compression and 10 ns/byte decompression
- crush 1.00    (cx)  13-15 ns/byte decompression